# Haskell: data type for representation of binary, hexadecimal, and octal

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define a data type to represent numbers in binary, octal and hexadecimal. The idea is to use this data type to define some functions in order to convert from octal to binary, from binary to hexadecimal and from octal to hexadecimal

This what I have until now..

```
data Number = Bin[Char] | Hex[Char]| Oct[Char]
                                          deriving Show

oct2Bin :: Number -> Number
bin2Hex :: Number -> Number
oct2Hex :: Number -> Number
```

But I'm stuck here and I don't know if I'm on the right track. I would appreciate any help I can get on this matter.

Comment: add a couple more of these representations and the combinatorial explosion (2^n converters) will bite you in the .... Why don't you convert from/to a numeric representation (`Int` or `Integer`)?

Answer (score 4):

You should simply save the number as one of the numerical types, preferably an integral one. That way, you can easily use a function like

```
type Base   = Int
type Number = Integral

repr :: Integral a => Base -> a -> String
```

But maybe there's already a function like that? And indeed, there is (in `Numeric`):

```
showIntAtBase :: (Integral a, Show a) => 
                 a                       -- the base
              -> (Int -> Char)           -- a function to transform single digits
                                         -- (in that base)
              -> a                       -- the number
              -> ShowS                   -- ShowS = String -> String
```

Therefore, `repr base number` is simply `showIntAtBase base conv number ""`:

```
repr base number = showIntAtBase base conv number ""
    where conv n  = (['0'..'9'] ++ ['a'..'z']) !! n
```

Although you might want to change `conv` to something else.

Also, `Numeric` already contains `showHex` and `showOct`. `showBinary` isn't in there, but together with repr above it's as simple as `showBin = repr 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Int` to represent your number and when you for some reason need a String representation, use `Number -> String` functions? Example:

```
type Number = Int

toBin :: Number -> String
toOct :: Number -> String
toHex :: Number -> String

toOct = show
... implement others as usual ...
```

Using a cannonical representation like this(in this case our representation is as Int) you can minimize required conversions between types. All operations on this type will work without conversions. Only conversion will happen when you need a String representation.

(There's also problems with combinatorial explosions like @Karoly mentioned in comments but as far as you guarantee that transitively all formats are reachable I think you can avoid it -- even though your implementation will probably be very inefficient)